# Unable to hide HTML within a UL + LI (CSS)

Tags: html, css, list, hide

Can anyone see or think why I can't hide items 5 onwards?

I would like to show ONLY items #1, #2, #3, and #4 with the rest all hidden (i.e. **completely** hidden from the code).

I can hide them from the client view but view source you can see the HTML - what am I doing wrong here?

I have tried:

```
visibility: hidden
```

As well as

```
display: none
```

And still, the code is there...

```css
ul>li {
  display: inline-block;
  /* You can also add some margins here to make it look prettier */
  width: 180px;
  zoom: 1;
  *display: inline;
  /* this fix is needed for IE7- */
}

ul>li:nth-of-type(1n+5) {
  display: none;
}

.speakercard {
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  max-width: 180px;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 14px;
}

button {
  border: none;
  outline: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px;
  color: white;
  background-color: #393939;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 100%;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}

button:hover,
a:hover {
  opacity: 0.7;
}

.image-cropper {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.profile-pic {
  display: inline;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 100%;
  width: auto;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <div class="speakercard">
      <div class="image-cropper">
        <img src="./img.jpeg" class="profile-pic" alt="" style="width:100%">
      </div>
      <p>1 Poo Doe</p>
      <p><button>Speaker Profile</button></p>
    </div>
  </li>

  <li>
    <div class="speakercard">
      <div class="image-cropper">
        <img src="./img.jpeg" class="profile-pic" alt="" style="width:100%">
      </div>
      <p>2 Doe</p>
      <p><button>Speaker Profile</button></p>
    </div>
  </li>

  <li>
    <div class="speakercard">
      <div class="image-cropper">
        <img src="./img.jpeg" class="profile-pic" alt="" style="width:100%">
      </div>
      <p>3 Doe</p>
      <p><button>Speaker Profile</button></p>
    </div>
  </li>

  <li>
    <div class="speakercard">
      <div class="image-cropper">
        <img src="./img.jpeg" class="profile-pic" alt="" style="width:100%">
      </div>
      <p>4 Doe</p>
      <p><button>Speaker Profile</button></p>
    </div>
  </li>

  <li>
    <div class="speakercard">
      <div class="image-cropper">
        <img src="./img.jpeg" class="profile-pic" alt="" style="width:100%">
      </div>
      <p>THIS SHOULD BE TOTALLY HIDDEN</p>
      <p><button>Speaker Profile</button></p>
    </div>
  </li>

  <li>
    <div class="speakercard">
      <div class="image-cropper">
        <img src="./img.jpeg" class="profile-pic" alt="" style="width:100%">
      </div>
      <p>THIS SHOULD BE TOTALLY HIDDEN</p>
      <p><button>Speaker Profile</button></p>
    </div>
  </li>

  <li>
    <div class="speakercard">
      <div class="image-cropper">
        <img src="./img.jpeg" class="profile-pic" alt="" style="width:100%">
      </div>
      <p>THIS SHOULD BE TOTALLY HIDDEN</p>
      <p><button>Speaker Profile</button></p>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Any idea how to make this happen?

Thanks!

Comment: why don't you try to add classes on the list item you want to show, and other another classes which you want to hide.

Comment: You can not remove anything from the source code client side. You can only manipulate the DOM which is built from the source code by the browser.

Comment: When your code snippet is ran then the items are hidden as expected. 
Must be a problem elsewhere.

Comment: You are not doing anything wrong, your _understanding_ of what CSS _does_ simply appears to be wrong.

Comment: in angular you shouldn't use document.querySelector or other dom things. This is angular. Check my demo in answer. You should use angular directives for this such as ngIf ,pipe etc... @henry

Answer (score 2):

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yzm1wz)
to hide from also  view source you should use `ngIf` directive rather than `css`

or you can use custom `pipe` to show what you want.

or you can connect to `ngFor` your elements and filter your list related what you want.

`css` just applied for design. It does for user view

for ngIf your html

```
<ul>
  <ng-container *ngFor="let data of personels;let i = index;">
    <li *ngIf="i<4">
      <div class="speakercard">
        <div class="image-cropper">
          <img src="{{data.img}}" class="profile-pic" alt="" style="width:100%">
        </div>
        <p>{{data.id}} {{data.Name}}</p>
        <p><button>Speaker Profile</button></p>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ng-container>
</ul>
```

in component.ts just create your array

```
personels=[
    {id:1,Name:"Poo Doe",img:"image1"},
    {id:2,Name:"Poo Doe",img:"image1"},
    {id:3,Name:"Poo Doe",img:"image1"},
    {id:4,Name:"Poo Doe",img:"image1"},
    {id:5,Name:"Poo Doe",img:"image1"},
    {id:6,Name:"Poo Doe",img:"image1"},
    {id:7,Name:"Poo Doe",img:"image1"}
  ]
```

and this is pipe [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ngg2eq)

create custom pipe

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
@Pipe({
  name: 'customPipe'
})

export class CustomPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(row: any[],n:number): any {
      return row.filter((x,idx)=>idx<n);       
  }
}
```

and in html use pipe

```
<ul>
    <li *ngFor="let data of personels|customPipe:4">
      <div class="speakercard">
        <div class="image-cropper">
          <img src="{{data.img}}" class="profile-pic" alt="" style="width:100%">
        </div>
        <p>{{data.id}} {{data.Name}}</p>
        <p><button>Speaker Profile</button></p>
      </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this CSS:

```
li {
  display: none;
}
li:nth-child(-n+3) {
  display: block;   
}
```

[check on codepen](https://codepen.io/pen/)

Comment: This will not remove the HTML from the source code which is what OP is asking about.

Comment: remove will not possible using CSS. But he can hide.

Comment: So basiscally it is not possible to completely hide HTML? I thought it was...

Comment: You can do it using JavaScript

Answer (score 0):

What you aim for is not possible with CSS! CSS is build just for styling the content of the DOM, not for malipulating the latter. If you really want to remove the items after the speaker profile 4, then you would have to use JavaScript to do so. JavaScript can manipulate the DOM on the client side. But why are you sending the profiles at all, if you want to remove them afterwards? Wouldn't it be easier to just not send them to your clients?

But if you *rellay* want to do so, here is how you can achieve your desired result.

```js
let speakercards = document.querySelectorAll('.speakercard');

for (let i = 0; i < speakercards.length; ++i) {
  if (i >= 4) {
    speakercards[i].remove()
  }
}
```

```css
ul>li {
  display: inline-block;
  /* You can also add some margins here to make it look prettier */
  width: 180px;
  zoom: 1;
  *display: inline;
  /* this fix is needed for IE7- */
}

/* ul>li:nth-of-type(1n+5) {
  display: none;
} */

.speakercard {
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  max-width: 180px;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 14px;
}

button {
  border: none;
  outline: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px;
  color: white;
  background-color: #393939;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 100%;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}

button:hover,
a:hover {
  opacity: 0.7;
}

.image-cropper {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.profile-pic {
  display: inline;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 100%;
  width: auto;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <div class="speakercard">
      <div class="image-cropper">
        <img src="./img.jpeg" class="profile-pic" alt="" style="width:100%">
      </div>
      <p>1 Poo Doe</p>
      <p><button>Speaker Profile</button></p>
    </div>
  </li>

  <li>
    <div class="speakercard">
      <div class="image-cropper">
        <img src="./img.jpeg" class="profile-pic" alt="" style="width:100%">
      </div>
      <p>2 Doe</p>
      <p><button>Speaker Profile</button></p>
    </div>
  </li>

  <li>
    <div class="speakercard">
      <div class="image-cropper">
        <img src="./img.jpeg" class="profile-pic" alt="" style="width:100%">
      </div>
      <p>3 Doe</p>
      <p><button>Speaker Profile</button></p>
    </div>
  </li>

  <li>
    <div class="speakercard">
      <div class="image-cropper">
        <img src="./img.jpeg" class="profile-pic" alt="" style="width:100%">
      </div>
      <p>4 Doe</p>
      <p><button>Speaker Profile</button></p>
    </div>
  </li>

  <li>
    <div class="speakercard">
      <div class="image-cropper">
        <img src="./img.jpeg" class="profile-pic" alt="" style="width:100%">
      </div>
      <p>THIS SHOULD BE TOTALLY HIDDEN</p>
      <p><button>Speaker Profile</button></p>
    </div>
  </li>

  <li>
    <div class="speakercard">
      <div class="image-cropper">
        <img src="./img.jpeg" class="profile-pic" alt="" style="width:100%">
      </div>
      <p>THIS SHOULD BE TOTALLY HIDDEN</p>
      <p><button>Speaker Profile</button></p>
    </div>
  </li>

  <li>
    <div class="speakercard">
      <div class="image-cropper">
        <img src="./img.jpeg" class="profile-pic" alt="" style="width:100%">
      </div>
      <p>THIS SHOULD BE TOTALLY HIDDEN</p>
      <p><button>Speaker Profile</button></p>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks for that @sam - the reason why I am doing this is to "give a sample" and the actual data is being sent via PHP (via a loop) so in fact the PHP could limit the data to only 4 per loop...if that makes sense

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't get what you mean, but it doesn't matter. It's not like you owe me an explanation. I'm glad if I could help you with that JavaScript snippet. If I have answered your question satisfactorily, I would be pleased about that green checkmark. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

It is my first answer on SO ever and guys above clearly gave you the solution but here is another way to accomplish the same result.

```
let myobj = document.querySelectorAll("ul > li:nth-of-type(1n+5)");
Array.from(myobj).map((el)=>el.remove())
```

Answer (score 0):

I would simply use ngClass directive:

```
 <ul>
  <li *ngFor="let user of users; let i = index" [ngClass]="{'hide': i>3}">
    <div class="speakercard">
      <div class="image-cropper">
        <img src="{{user.img}}" class="profile-pic" alt="" style="width:100%">
      </div>
      <p>{{user.id}} {{user.name}}</p>
      <p><button>Speaker Profile</button></p>
    </div>
  </li>
  </ul>
```

CSS :

```
.hide{
display:none;
}
```

You can also replace hide with bootstrap class d-none:

```
<li *ngFor="let user of users; let i = index" [ngClass]="{'d-none': i>3}">
```